# Need suggestion in logic : find specific sub string in a system.collections.generic.ienumerable<system.text.regularexpression.match>

Tags: c#, enumerable

ex:

I have a variable defined as below

```
system.collections.generic.ienumerable<system.text.regularexpression.match>

ex:item.tostring=('description:this is a test string','found Resolution:this is a test res','we have found the rootcause:this is test root cause ')
```

i have three string variables defined as below

```
v1='Description' v2='Resolution' v3='rootcause'
```

Now these three strings are part of the/substring enumerable.tostring .

I need to check if this enumerable has all these three strings involved in it or not .
if yes :true
if no :false

detailed help is appreciated

Comment: its in C# ....I need the logic or function which can be used here .I can make corrections depending on the language

Comment: Here are the docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8. To me this seems specific. Why not use Contains() -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8 ?